# CommunicationException when calling MVC Service from ObjectDataSource Select method

Tags: vb.net, wcf, web-applications, wshttpbinding, communicationexception

**I am getting the exception below in my web application:
"The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state"
Stack Trace:**

> " Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan
>   timeout)  Exception rethrown at [0]:      at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)     at
>   System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan
>   timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.Close()     at
>   System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.System.IDisposable.Dispose()     at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.ReleaseInstance(Object
>   instance)     at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSource.Select() 
>   at BudgeteerWeb.EditTransaction.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   in
>   C:\Develop\Budgeteer\BudgeteerWeb\BudgeteerWeb\MemberPages\Transactions\Edit.aspx.vb:line
>   27"

**I am calling a WCF Service from within a select method used by a ObjectDataSource. Everything works OK if I'm not using message-based security. But as soon as I turn on the wsHttpBinding with the ClientCredentials, I get the above error. Not sure what I'm missing.**

**ASP Code:**

**Code Behind:
Function That is used by objectDataSource select method:**

```
Protected Function getTransaction(ByVal userID As String, ByVal transactionID As Int64)   
    As BudgeteerService.Transaction

    Dim transaction As BudgeteerService.Transaction = New BudgeteerService.Transaction
    transaction = wcfProxy.GetTransaction(userID, transactionID)

    Return transaction

End Function

Try
    transactionID = Int64.Parse(Request.QueryString("TransactionID"))

    Dim userIdParm As Parameter = New Parameter

    TransactionDataSource.Select() '**EXCEPTION GETS THROWN HERE**
    FormView1.DataSource = TransactionDataSource
    FormView1.DataBind()
Catch timeOutEx As TimeoutException
    Throw timeOutEx
Catch comEx As CommunicationException
    Throw comEx
Catch ex As Exception
    Throw New Exception("An error occured while trying to retrieve this transaction")
End Try
```

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Finally found an answer: Apparently I needed to override the objectcreating and objectdisposing events. In the objectcreating, I set the e.objectinstance to my in session proxy. Since this event seems to create its own instance and I was using ClientCredential userName based message security, these values were not being set and it was throwing a fault. Once I overrode the event all was fine. In the objectdisposing event I had to set e.cancel = true so that the object wouldn't be disposed afterwards.